# Delete files while excluding files using find

Tags: find

This command is not DWIM-compliant:

```
find . \( -name .svn -prune -false \) -o \( -empty -delete \)
find: The -delete action atomatically turns on -depth, but -prune 
      does nothing when -depth is in effect.  If you want to 
      carry on anyway, just explicitly use the -depth option.
```

Adding `-depth` disables the effect of `-prune`, which means `.svn` directories are also deleted. So: Which `find` syntax (if any) can be used to prune and then delete some of the non-pruned paths, without using other tools like `rm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-path`, it's not POSIX but supported by many implementations :

```
find . \! -path "*/.svn/*" -empty -delete
```

`-regex` is an option too.

Comment: I think all the implementations that have `-delete` also have `-path`. So this solution should work everywhere that's withing the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If whitespace is not a problem, something like this will work

```
find . \( -name .svn -prune -false \) -o -print | tac | xargs -L rm -f
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's a big performance win when the parts of the tree we're avoiding with `-prune` are large.   The downside is that -delete  will delete things as soon as it sees a leaf, but this command has to wait until `find` exits.  So if there is a lot of stuff to delete, but not much of the search space was pruned, it may not be a win.

Comment: Sorry, whitespace is always a problem. But maybe there's a way to use `tac` with a `\0` separator?